# How to handle disconnection events on mobile devices with SignalR?

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket, signalr

I have a couple of iPads that run a web app.  The web app talks to the server via signalR.  The reason for this is that the server needs to send specific data to a specific iPad.  Therefore it needs to keep track of which iPad is on/off.

iPad has following methods to put the application to sleep.

1. iPad goes to sleep
2. User kills Safari
3. iPad runs out of memory

How do I detect these on the server?  So I know not to send them data.
I've tried the disconnection event, but that takes time to fire (45 second by default or so).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you won't know for sure until the connection times out, because SignalR isn't going to know before then.

Even in the case that seems most like it should result in some sort of signal you can trap - the iPad transitioning to standby - there is no notification that you can get in your JavaScript code that will let you tidy up your connections before that happens.

Depending on the nature of the data you are sending to the client you might be able to minimize the buffering by switching to a data available notification format where the server sends a minimal data packet to the client to inform it that data is waiting to be retrieved, then have the client side request the information.  In some scenarios this can drastically reduce the amount of data that is being buffered either in your application or in the transport layer.

Of course if you have several kilobytes of data per notification and you have to preserve them all for sequential delivery this will only reduce the buffering at the transport layer, moving it back a step and making it the responsibility of the application.

Another option is to have the clients send a heartbeat running from a JS timer instance.  Every second or so (depending on how real-time you need) the client calls a method on the server that essentially just lets you know which ones are still live.  After a few failed check-ins - 5 missed hearbeats for instance - you can assume that the client is gone and stop sending it information.  The server would need to track last heartbeat for each client connection and each time you want to send something to a particular client just check if it has checked in recently.  If not, let the data provider know that the client is offline until it checks in again, at which point you probably need to tell it to reload and start over.